# Android Studio 3.6.3 How to get rid of ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath' (androidx.fragment:fragment)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.6

I'm tired of getting this error every third/fourth time I try to build project:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:[1.2.0].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

It also effects `':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath'` and `':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath'` (shows the same error for them).

Also sometimes it goes after the following build error (internet connection is surely stable):

```
Unknown host 'repo.maven.apache.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle
```

There were no changes in `build.gradle` files or any other gradle files before this error came.

It would be nice if you help to get rid of it. Gradle-plugin version = "1.3.71".